# Postgresql via Helm not installing

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, minikube, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-helm

I am attempting to install postgres via helm using the latest [stable](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql) and it isn't installing the persistent volume properly. I am installing it in Minikube and for some reason it doesn't appear to be able to hostMount properly.

**Error (on the deployment, pod, and replica set)**

> PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "postgres-postgresql" Error: lstat
>   /tmp/hostpath-provisioner/pvc-c713429d-e2a3-11e7-9ca9-080027231d54: no
>   such file or directory Error syncing pod

When I look at the persistent volume it appears to be running properly.  In case it helps here is my persistent volume yaml:

```
{
  "kind": "PersistentVolume",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "pvc-c713429d-e2a3-11e7-9ca9-080027231d54",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/persistentvolumes/pvc-c713429d-e2a3-11e7-9ca9-080027231d54",
    "uid": "c71850e1-e2a3-11e7-9ca9-080027231d54",
    "resourceVersion": "396568",
    "creationTimestamp": "2017-12-16T20:57:50Z",
    "annotations": {
      "hostPathProvisionerIdentity": "8979806c-dfba-11e7-862f-080027231d54",
      "pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by": "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "capacity": {
      "storage": "8Gi"
    },
    "hostPath": {
      "path": "/tmp/hostpath-provisioner/pvc-c713429d-e2a3-11e7-9ca9-080027231d54",
      "type": ""
    },
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteOnce"
    ],
    "claimRef": {
      "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
      "namespace": "default",
      "name": "postgres-postgresql",
      "uid": "c713429d-e2a3-11e7-9ca9-080027231d54",
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "resourceVersion": "396550"
    },
    "persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy": "Delete",
    "storageClassName": "standard"
  },
  "status": {
    "phase": "Bound"
  }
}
```

Persistent Volume Claim Yaml:

```
{
  "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "postgres-postgresql",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/persistentvolumeclaims/postgres-postgresql",
    "uid": "c713429d-e2a3-11e7-9ca9-080027231d54",
    "resourceVersion": "396588",
    "creationTimestamp": "2017-12-16T20:57:50Z",
    "labels": {
      "app": "postgres-postgresql",
      "chart": "postgresql-0.8.3",
      "heritage": "Tiller",
      "release": "postgres"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "control-plane.alpha.kubernetes.io/leader": "{\"holderIdentity\":\"897980a2-dfba-11e7-862f-080027231d54\",\"leaseDurationSeconds\":15,\"acquireTime\":\"2017-12-16T20:57:50Z\",\"renewTime\":\"2017-12-16T20:57:52Z\",\"leaderTransitions\":0}",
      "pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed": "yes",
      "pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller": "yes",
      "volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner": "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteOnce"
    ],
    "resources": {
      "requests": {
        "storage": "8Gi"
      }
    },
    "volumeName": "pvc-c713429d-e2a3-11e7-9ca9-080027231d54",
    "storageClassName": "standard"
  },
  "status": {
    "phase": "Bound",
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteOnce"
    ],
    "capacity": {
      "storage": "8Gi"
    }
  }
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is exactly the problem you are facing? Can we see the `kubectl describe po` output of the failing pod?

Comment: I'm not sure why you got downvoted here — this is a real issue and the question describes it well.  I was able to reproduce it with just a normal helm install of postgres.

Answer (score 5):

You may be running into this issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2256

The problem is there's a bug in the hostpath volume provisioner that encounters an error when the 'subPath' field is present in the Deployment resource (event if the field has an empty value).

Here's a workaround that worked for me - unpack the postgresql chart and comment out the following line in deployment.yaml:

```
      # subPath: {{ .Values.persistence.subPath }}
```

Then redeploy the modified chart.  If you're reliant on the 'subPath' field, this workaround won't work for you.

Note: This issue is also present on Kubernetes on Docker-for-Mac (which is where I've encountered it).

Comment: This resolved the issue with helm postgres for me as well.